# Organizing Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to organize my firestore cloud function so that every function in a separate file, i found a great article [here](https://codeburst.io/organizing-your-firebase-cloud-functions-67dc17b3b0da)
and i use this code

```
const files = glob.sync('./**/*.f.js', { cwd: __dirname, ignore: './node_modules/**' })
for (let f = 0, fl = files.length; f < fl; f++) {
    const file = files[f]
    const functionName = camelCase(file.slice(0, -5).split('/').join('_')) // Strip off '.f.js'
    if (!process.env.FUNCTION_NAME || process.env.FUNCTION_NAME === functionName) {
        console.log(functionName+": "+file)
        // tslint:disable-next-line: no-var-requires
        exports[functionName] = require(file)
    }
}
```

I organized my functions in this way and work correctly but in console shows something that i don't understand why this happened.

in the console shows that every function are exported multiple times

for example i have 2 functions inside dbID folder when deployed it shows something like that

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUrNW.png

if you see that every function also export all other functions inside other directory

My question is this can make problem ? or any performance issue ? or any better way to organize functions without grouping ?

thanks

Comment: I don't understand that screenshot.  It doesn't look like it comes from the Firebase console or any Firebase tool I know of.

Comment: yes, i just copy it from firebase. here the full screenshot https://ibb.co/FsRc6dz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're deploying to Node 10, you will probably want to change your statements to include the new environment variables. `FUNCTION_TARGET` instead of `FUNCTION_NAME`

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#nodejs_10_and_subsequent_runtimes

> The Node.js 10 runtime automatically sets fewer environment variables than previous runtimes supported by Cloud Functions.

```
if (!process.env.FUNCTION_TARGET || process.env.FUNCTION_TARGET === functionName) {
    console.log(functionName+": "+file)
    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-var-requires
    exports[functionName] = require(file)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at is just the output of `console.log()` in your code.  For all code that executes at the global scope of your functions, it will get executed for every function executed in your index.js.  If you don't want to see that output in the log, just remove the call to `console.log()`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, ```console.log()``` is not my problem, i know how the code works and i watched all you videos about Understanding Cloud Functions. but the way console shows, i think that it execute exports multiple times for each function. can we sure not causing any issue or better way than this way?  if not causing any issue, i will ignore it. Thanks

Comment: The global code will run once for each function for each server instance that's been allocated for it. You can expect it to run multiple times as time goes on. I don't see a problem here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation

Comment: It's customary to upvote helpful answers and mark them as correct, if you find that to be true.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple module / npm package called `better-firebase-functions`

Simply `npm i better-firebase-functions`, and then:

```
import exportCloudFunctions from 'better-firebase-functions'
exportCloudFunctions(__dirname, __filename, exports, './', './**/*.js')
```

It does everything automatically and will speed up your cold boot, without you having to worry about implementation details.

Read the docs for details on how to organise your function files (must `export default` in TS and `module.exports.default =` in JS) as it may change from the time of writing this.